# What is the right way to export the class to be extended from other classes NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, sinon

Base class looks like this:

```
class BaseReport {
    constructor(reportName) {
        this.reportName = reportName;
    }
    async generateReport(accountId, request) {
        let results = await this.getDataFromDb(request);
        results = this.formatResults(results);
        return updatedResults;
    }

    formatResults(data) {
        //Some logig here
        return  result
    }

    getDataFromDb(request) {
        //Logic to get data from database
        return errorRequest;
    }

}

module.exports = BaseReport;
```

The I have another class that extends Base class:

```
const BaseReport = require("./base.service");

class DataReport extends BaseReport {
    constructor() {
        super('dataReport');
    }

    formatResults(data) {
        //Logic to format results in a different way
        return data;
    }
}

module.exports = new DataReport();
```

So far everything works well. `DataReport` class doesn't need to implement the method `getDataFromDB` because it is inherited from `BaseReport` class.

The problem starts when I am writing unit/integration tests.

When I try to stub function getData() it is not working (it is not being stubbed but instead it is calling the method and making the database call.
I understand WHY is happening... In `BaseReport` class I am exporting the class itself. So when I create an object on my unit tests and try to stub the function, that is not the same method and object which is initialized when the application is running. Every time you use the keyword "new" creates a new object and has its own methods.
If I want to stub a method from DataReport class it works fine because in there I am exporting an object of that class (`module.exports = new DataReport();`). In this case, it can only exist one copy of the object and so only one copy of the methods as well.

Now I can not do the same for `BaseReport` class because my understanding is that you CAN NOT extend `BaseReport` class if I exported a new object (`module.exports = new BaseReport();`).

What is the proper way to implement this in order to also have the unit tests working??

Comment: Can you post your failing test? Because Sinon able to stub class method (`sinon.stub(Class.prototype, "method")`) and object method (`sinon.stub(object, "method")`).

Comment: What exactly are you testing? Please provide test code